# How do I find the exact value of $\cos^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble finding the exact value of $\cos^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$ in radians.

I was able to figure out that:

$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}\right) &= \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{12} + \frac{4\pi}{12}\right) &\text{Split into known unit circle values.}\\
    &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) &\text{Reduce.}\\
    &= \cos(a + b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) &\text{Use Cosine Identity.}\\
    &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) &\text{Substitute values.}\\
    &= \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2} \times \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right) &\text{Evaluate.}\\
    &= \frac{\sqrt2}{4} - \frac{\sqrt6}{4}\\
    &= \frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt6}{4}\\
\end{align}
$$

I know that $\cos^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$ is not all that different, but the square exponent ($^2$) is throwing me for a loop.

Can anyone break it down for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try the double angle identity
$$\cos^2\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos 2\alpha).$$

Comment: So would I just plug in `5pi/12` in for α and work it out from there?

Comment: I think you mean $\cos^2(a)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2a))$.

Comment: @Eric, same question: Would I then just plug in `5pi/12` in for α and work it out from there?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Yes. Try it.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic, yes.  The left hand side is the value you are looking for and, conveniently, you probably know the value of $\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$ .

Comment: @Eric, I don't know the value of **cos(2 * 5pi/12)**...?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic I think you probably do, since $2\cdot \frac{5\pi}{12} = \frac{5\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @rogerl, *facepalm* I hate when I miss the easy stuff like that. Ok, I've gotten down to: **cos^2(5pi/12) = 1/2(1+(-sqrt(3)/2))**. Now what?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Now aren't you done? You can expand/simplify algebraically if you want, but basically that is the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos\alpha=-\cos(\pi-\alpha)$,
$$
\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}=-\cos\left(\pi-\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)=
-\cos\frac{7\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}
$$
Then
$$
\cos^2\frac{5\pi}{12}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^2
=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}
$$